Kmean get good group separation
I have a basic code for use Kmeans with sklearn
    scaled = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(points)

    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=nb_clusters) # , random_state=42 , init='random', algorithm='elkan'
    kmeans.fit(scaled)
    labels = kmeans.labels_
    centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_

But i don't success to have my two groups well separated

Does someone know what's wrong or what is lacking please ?
Thank you in advance.

The k-means algorithm is based on the assumption of spherically shaped clusters with a common diameter, e. g. isotropic Gaussian-distributed clusters. Your data does not fit this assumption.
First you should plot your data with a 1:1 aspect ratio to better understand what is going on. You will see that the separation of your two groups circled in blue is smaller as compared to their spread in y-direction.
Second, you should observe that the group to the right includes much, much less data points as compared to the group on the left. To the algorithm, the points on the right are mere outliers of the distribution it tries to model.
To sum it up, k-means is probably not a good fit for your data. Mean shift, although maybe overkill, should be a much better fit.

Few potential issues and suggestions to improve your clustering results:

The initialization method for centroids can impact the clustering results. Using init='k-means++' can lead to better results as it spreads out the initial cluster centers.
Ensure that the number of clusters (nb_clusters) is set correctly according to your data. You might want to try different values to see which one works best.
If the data is not well-separated, KMeans might not perform well. Consider using other clustering algorithms like DBSCAN or Gaussian Mixture Models if KMeans doesn't work.


Hello, thank you for your answer,
k-means++ is the default one so the one present on my image.
I want well 2 cluster
As you can see on the image, they are well separated
